# In BASH, delete everything between two sets of characters

Tags: regex, bash, shell, vim

I've combined a bunch of email files into one large text file & now I'm trying to delete all the header lines from the emails out of this new text files. I have a set of unique characters I can use as markers to delete between them, but I'm coming up short with finding a RegEx that will strip out the header files. An example set is below (including the two asterisks and the double equals at the bottom).

```
**


 w54cs6547wem;         Sat, 30 Oct 2010 00:06:43 -0700 (PDT)
 s10mr13764658ybi.218.1288422402631;         Sat, 30 Oct 2010 00:06:42 -0700 (PDT)


p13si451872ybk.2.2010. .36;         Sat, 30 Oct 2010 00:06:42 -0700 (PDT)

  Sat, 30 Oct 2010 02:01:23 -0500 

Date: Sat, 30 Oct 2010 02:01:22 -0500 Subject: 
Message-ID:  
Thread-Index: Act4ABHi0HfIPTIzRwe9oy8ojziTig==
```

Comment: I was thinking I could use the double asterisk and the double equals as markers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i '/\*\*/,/==/d' FILE
```

changes your file in place (-i),

```
sed '/\*\*/,/==/d' FILE > MODIFIED
```

saves the modification to a newly created file.

Comment: Thanks @user unknown - `sed '/\*\*/,/==/d' FILE > MODIFIED` is exactly what I needed &/or used

Answer (score 2):

I don't know bash replacement syntax, but the regex you want is:

```
/\*\*.*?==/
```

In PHP, the code would be:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\*\*.*?==/', '', $str);
```

Hopefully you can translate that into bash without any trouble.

**Explanation:**

The trick here is the `.*?`. The `?` makes the `.*` lazy, so it will start at `**` and match everything until the *first* `==` it finds. Without the `?`, the `.*` would be greedy and grab everything between the first `**` and the last `==` in the document. So if you have something like this:

```
**foo==bar **baz==quux **abc==xyz
```

...using `/\*\*.*?==/` as your regex would give you `bar quux xyz`, while `/\*\*.*==/` would give only `xyz`.

Comment: actually, php's installed on the box, so I can give this a shot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do that, most probably you would be processing the entire file in memory. Here's a line by line approach.

```
$> cat  file
some words
here that i want
**


 w54cs6547wem;         Sat, 30 Oct 2010 00:06:43 -0700 (PDT)
 s10mr13764658ybi.218.1288422402631;         Sat, 30 Oct 2010 00:06:42 -0700 (PDT)


p13si451872ybk.2.2010. .36;         Sat, 30 Oct 2010 00:06:42 -0700 (PDT)

  Sat, 30 Oct 2010 02:01:23 -0500

Date: Sat, 30 Oct 2010 02:01:22 -0500 Subject:
Message-ID:
Thread-Index: Act4ABHi0HfIPTIzRwe9oy8ojziTig==

other words
here that i also want

$> awk '/^\*\*/{f=1;next} f&&/==$/{f=0;next} f{next} !f' file
some words
here that i want

other words
here that i also want
```

The idea is to set a flag when the `**` is found, then skip the line until `==` is found.

Answer (score 0):

It is easily expressible in perl: `cat file | perl -p -i -e 'undef $_ if /^\*\*/ .. /==$/'`. Same for sed: `cat file | sed -e '/^\*\*/,/==$/d'`.

Comment: @user unknown: It is not useless if you don't want to overwrite a file (I usually want to check what is done before performing something destructive). For perl you could replace `cat file | perl -p -i -e ...` with `perl -p -i -e ... file` and get changes immediately applied, for sed it is `sed -i -e ... file`. If you meant replacing `cat file | cmd` with `cmd <file`, then it is not useless: it enables you to change `cat file | less` to `cat file | sed ...` more easily than if you wrote `less file`.

Comment: But sed already takes as parameter the file to work on `sed '/^\*\*/,/==$/d' file` gives you everything you need - the -i is orthogonal to invoking cat and pipe. Appending ` | less` is as well an independent option.

Comment: @user unknown There is a number of situations (not just current one) when I need to change from `cat file | cmd1` to `cat file | cmd2`, so writing `cat file | cmd` instead of `cmd file` or `cmd <file` has become a habit because it is more efficient. And this saves me from remembering some sed options: I know that `perl -p -i -e` and `sed -i -e` will replace a file, know that `sed -e` will process stdin. I do not want to know what `sed` will do with file arguments when I do not supply `-i`: knowing about `cat | sed -e` covers my needs well enough and I do not have unlimited memory in my brains.